# basic p-type mosfet circuit, breaks mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, p-channel

So I've made this basic circuit to drive Vout between ~0V and ~1.65V.
The default state should be ~0V, hence I use a p-type mosfet:
https://docs.rs-online.com/d95a/0900766b800ae907.pdf

Now, for some reason it looks like the fet has broken down after applying a voltage to the gate the first time by closing the switch (s1). I'm having quite a hard time in fet-based circuit design so maybe somebody could help me a bit in what I'm doing wrong or how I'm mis-understanding the situation?

The source is driven by a 5V supply. R1 = 20k, R2 and R3 are 10k.
Q1 is an FDV304P P-channel mosfet as given in the link above.

The circuit:
[image: the schematics of my circuit]

The purpose of this circuit is to drive an IC's enable pin. By default this enable should be turned low but when the switch is closed, the enable should be high. The switch simulates a IO pin from another IC.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of your circuit. You should edit the question rather than answer in a comment so that people do not need to read the comments to find that information.

Comment: The mosfet shunts Vout to GND as drawn

Comment: I think you applied a positive VGS to a P MOS. In any case, to avoid mistakes put a resistance with the gate, that limits the current. E.g. 1 kohm would limit to 5 mA max. And it will not break.

Comment: @andrea thanks for the response, yes i did exactly that. the 5V source is postive 5V relative to GND.

Comment: To drive an enable pin, you do not need a mosfet with your switch. You only need your mechanical switch and a pull down resistor. If you want to limit the voltage on the enable pin to 1.65V, (with a 5V supply) you need a second resistor in series with your switch. So, is there another reason for your circuit?

Comment: Ok, sorry for my late response but what seems to keep you busy is the goal of this circuit. The enable pin this Vout is driving, has a threshold voltage just a voltage below 1.65V. Using the FET we can drive the enable pin to low when the 5V is dropping. A sort of undervoltage detection. The enable pin will reach a lower treshold voltage disabling the IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @"Math Keeps Me Busy" says you can do this without a mosfet, but if you would like to use one you can do it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwIDRv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first one uses a P-mosfet.  Changes from yours that I have made:

- turn around S/D terminals (having recently made the same mistake myself, I like showing the body diode so I can tell whether I've gotten it the right way around!)
- Use it as a high-side switch.  It passes, or not, the high rail.
  R3 keep Q1 turned off by pulling up the gate to the high rail
- SW1 turns on Q1 by pulling the gate down relative to the source
  terminal (high rail).
- In this schematic and yours, the gate is pulled
  all the way down to 0V, which means Vgs = -5V; this is within the
  specs of this FET but if you were using a higher voltage BAT1 you
  could increase R4 in order to control how low you pull the gate.

The second one uses an N-MOSFET as a low-side switch.  It will invert the output (Vout* will be 1.66V when SW3 is open, and 0V when SW3 is closed)

Comment: Thanks Daniel! you say 'the same mistake'. Could you tell a bit more on what this 'mistake' then actually is / does and what causes it? that is the part I'd like to learn about a bit more.

Comment: 'the same mistake'....  just that I recently put a P-mosfet into a schematic upside-down.  N-type are intuitive,  P-type are tricksy/backwards/upside-down.  Gotta make sure parasitic body diode in N or P type are reverse biased, unless you very deliberately intend otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First, the use of a mosfet is unnecessary to drive an enable pin of virtually any IC. One can simply use a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1R7xq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming the enable pin does not source or sink excessive current, when the switch is open, the enable pin will be at 0V and when the switch is closed, the enable pin will be at 1.66V (close to the 1.65V you intended). If the enable pin *does* source or sink significant current, the voltages will be be 0 and 1.66V. R1 and R2 may be decreased to compensate, (with the side effect that more power will be used when the switch is closed).

Second, the MOSFET you have chosen (like most mosfets) has a body diode connected between the source and drain pins. As configured, the drain (and hence Vout) will never rise beyond 0.6-0.7V above the source/ground.